# Should I use pull (AJAX) or push (WebSocket) to scale for large amount of users?

Tags: web-applications, single-page-application

I need my web app to scale to 10,000 users. I need to implement a functionality which notifies the user about certain events, for example, the job that you submitted has finished, you have new suggestions to optimize and so on. I'm thinking of 2 implementation strategies:

(pull) Every minute to send an AJAX request to the server to ask for new notifications if there are any

(push) To use WebSocket and notify user when there is a new notification

Which one would be recommended?

DETAILS ABOUT THE WEB APP:

The Backend language that I'm using is Java running on tomcat 6 (yes, I saw that only tomcat 8 begins to support WebSocket so I might end up having to upgrade).

The application is a single-page web app. This notification feature is not necessary to be real-time, I'm just concerned with which option is more scalable.

Requests are dealt with via AJAX.

Comment: You gave us little information about your app. Scalability depends on alot of things. Pushing will use more resources than ajax requesting every minute, but ajax requesting every minute will be far from a realtime app. I don't know what kind of reply you're expecting, but pushing on most cases is a better approach.

Comment: @Imaqtpie What are these "alot of things"?

Comment: The language you're using, your application, server specs, server configuration, how you deal with requests etc. Mostly your application though. It could be something lightweight, or very heavy, or coded without any optimization. So, you can't tell if it's going to handle 10,000 users with zero information. Do some tests, gather some information and ask it on Server Fault.

My other reply still stands though. Pushing is a better use practice. Pulling is pretty old, not realtime, and will lead performance issues when you lower request per second from 1 minutes.

Comment: @Imaqtpie I've added the details.

Comment: Obligatory "WebSocket doesn't work on IE8, which is still widely used" comment.